# Compare lists of strings regarding the suffixes of their respective elements

Tags: python, performance, list, string-comparison

Suppose I have a list like this

```
myList = ['A_x','B_x','C_x','D_x']
```

and a list of lists like this

```
myListOfList = [['A_x','B_y','C_x','D_z'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_u','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','B_y','D_y', 'E_l'],
                ['A_y','P_y','T_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','D_y','B_y'],
                ['A_z','C_z','D_z','B_z']]
```

Now I would like to determine all lists in `myListOfList` which are identical with `myList` except of the suffixes of the respective elements in these lists whereby the suffixes of the elements in the sublist of `myListOfList` have to be identical. So in the example above I would then like to find:

```
#all elements as in myList but with suffix y instead of x
['A_y','B_y','C_y','D_y']
#all elements as in myList but with suffix y instead of x but in different order
['A_y','C_y','D_y','B_y']
#all elements as in myList but with suffix z instead of x but in different order
['A_z','C_z','D_z','B_z']
```

but I don't want to find the other ones as their elements have not the same suffixes, the length differs from `myList's` lengths or the first parts of the elements differ from the elements in `myList`.

I implemented that as follows:

```
myList = ['A_x','B_x','C_x','D_x']

myListOfList = [['A_x','B_y','C_x','D_z'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_u','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','B_y','D_y', 'E_l'],
                ['A_y','P_y','T_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','D_y','B_y'],
                ['A_z','C_z','D_z','B_z']]

listOfInd=[]                
for ind, sl in enumerate(myListOfList):
    if len(sl) == len(myList) and [x.endswith(sl[0][-2:]) for x in sl].count(False) == 0:
        tempList = zip(myList, sorted(sl))
        allTrue = True
        for el in tempList:
            #print el[0]
            if el[0][:-2] != el[1][:-2]:
                allTrue = False

        if(allTrue):
            listOfInd.append(ind)
```

which gives me indeed the correct output: `listOfInd = [1, 6, 7]`.

To explain two elements of this code:

This checks whether all elements in a list `sl` have the same suffix:

```
[x.endswith(sl[0][-2:]) for x in sl].count(False) == 0
```

This checks whether the string `el` is the same except of the suffix (last two elements of the string):

```
if el[0][:-2] != el[1][:-2]
```

So what I do is to go through each list in `myListOfList`, if the number of elements in this list is the same as in `myList` and all elements in this list have the same suffixes, I `zip` this list with `myList`. Then I go through each element in this zipped list and compare the strings until the suffixes.

The code works, however, it looks very inefficient and I wonder whether there is a more "pythonic" way on doing this without so many loops. Can anyone think of a more efficient way of implementing this?

Comment: are `['A_y','B_y','C_z','D_z']` and `['A_x','D_k','B_x','C_k']` considered equal?

Comment: @mescalinum: No, the suffixes in a list have to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a set if the prefixes, check if the prefix set is a subset of the prefixes of each element in your sublists, if it is then check if all suffixes are the same.

```
st = {s[0] for s in myList}
l = []
for ind, sub in enumerate(myListOfList):
    k = sub[0][-1]
    if st.issubset(ch[0] for ch in sub) and all((ch[-1] == k for ch in sub)):
        l.append(ind)
print(l)
[1, 6, 7]
```

You can put it in a list comp if you prefer:

```
inds = [ind for ind, sub in enumerate(myListOfList) if st.issubset(ch[0] for ch in sub)
        and all(ch[-1] == sub[0][-1] for ch in sub)]

print(inds)
[1, 6, 7]
```

You can also make a couple of optimizations, if the length of any sub is not equal to the length of myList we cannot have matches:, with that we can use all to see if each element[0] from each sub is in the set as that may be a little bit faster.

```
l = []
ln_m = len(myList)
for ind, sub in enumerate(myListOfList):
    k = sub[0][-1]
    if len(sub) == ln_m and all(ch[0] in st for ch in sub) and all(ch[-1] == k for ch in sub):
        l.append(ind)
```

Comment: That looks fantastic! And seems much faster than my implementation. I'll test it for other data sets. I upvote it now and might accept it later on!

Comment: @Cleb, no worries, I will have another crack at improving in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab at it using sets. Note that I'm using string subindexing instead of splitting on '_' or regexes since I'm assuming a very rigid format.

```
myList = ['A_x','B_x','C_x','D_x']

myListOfList = [['A_x','B_y','C_x','D_z'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_u','B_y','C_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','B_y','D_y', 'E_l'],
                ['A_y','P_y','T_y','D_y'],
                ['A_y','B_y','C_y'],
                ['A_y','C_y','D_y','B_y'],
                ['A_z','C_z','D_z','B_z']]

myList_prefixes = set((x[0] for x in myList))

listOfInd = []
for idx, sublist in enumerate(myListOfList):
    if len(sublist) != len(myList):
        continue
    sublist_suffixes = set((x[-1] for x in sublist))
    # ensure that you only have one kind of suffix, like only x or only y
    if len(sublist_suffixes) != 1:
        continue
    sublist_prefixes = set((x[0] for x in sublist))
    # make sure the prefixes match
    if sublist_prefixes != myList_prefixes:
        continue
    listOfInd.append(idx)
print listOfInd
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative! For this example there is almost no difference regarding the speed; I will test it on bigger data sets. I upvote your answer since it is a working solution and a nice alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(l1,l2):
    def normalize(l):
        r = defaultdict(set)
        for a,b in map(lambda x: x.split('_'), l): r[b].add(a)
        return set(tuple(sorted(v)) for v in r.values())
    n1,n2 = normalize(l1),normalize(l2)
    return len(n1)==1 and len(n2)==1 and n1==n2
```

Test:

```
>>> [i for i,l in enumerate(myListOfList) if compare(myList,l)]
[1, 6, 7]
```

One little remark about the normalize() function inside the compare() function: it will make a group of sorted prefixes for each suffix:

```
>>> normalize(myList)
{('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')}

>>> normalize(['A_x','B_x','C_x','D_y'])
{('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D',)}

>>> normalize(['A_x','B_y','C_z','D_x'])
{('A', 'D'), ('B',), ('C',)}
```

and in fact would allow you to compare lists as in my comment to your question if you remove the `len(n1)==1 and len(n2)==1` condition.

Comment: Works fine as well but seems slower than Padraic Cunningham's solution. I upvote it anyway :)